# Retrofit Android + Spring Boot Server images uploading return Bad Request error

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I read a lot issues with that here, but it's not working for me. May be I doing something wrong?

my retrofit Interface:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/api/v1/services/add")
suspend fun addServiceAsync(@Part("newService") service: ServiceApiData,
                            @Part imageFile:MultipartBody.Part?,
                            @Header("Authorization") jwt:String?): StatusAndStrApi?
```

And Spring RestController part is

```
@PostMapping("/add")
ResponseEntity<?> addService(@RequestPart(name = "newService") ServiceServer service,
                             @RequestPart("imageFileFromClient") MultipartFile imageFile
                             )
```

Here how i create Multipatr.Body:

```
MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
            "imageFileFromClient",
            fileImage.name,
            fileImage.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull()
        )
```

Here what server return me:

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- 400 http://server:8080/api/v1/services/add (301ms)
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Pragma: no-cache
    Expires: 0
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    Content-Type: application/json
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Date: Fri, 03 Sep 2021 05:11:18 GMT
    Connection: close
    {"timestamp":"2021-09-03T05:11:18.689+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","path":"/api/v1/services/add"}
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (110-byte body)
I/System.out: close [socket][/100.107.22.171:34172]
```

Comment: Did you try the same API in Postman or any other REST API testing tool? If yes, please [edit] the question and post a screenshot here. This will be helpful to understand how your API works and your code is proper or not.

Comment: @Shashanth i testing with "curl" but i never worked with multipart so i don't know what type of request should i send. Anyway i found bug, ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BODY WAS NULL, but it mustn't be. Don't allow Multipartbody be nullable. Never.

Answer (score 0):

Try using https instead of http.

Comment: Can you please explain why do you think it will work?

Comment: I had this issue then i changed address to https and  also created a new instance of okhttpsclient inside the GET/POST function and it worked for me.You can also check if you are not using multiple instances of okhttp client .

Comment: sounds pretty strange, anyway I'll try it later

Comment: Yeah, it's not working, because i don't have ssl